# Working principle of clamped circuit with finite load resistance?

Tags: diodes, analog, diode-clamp

Please help me understand the output waveform for the clamper circuit to the following input. i do understand without load resistance, but with load resistance i cant seem to work it out
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a positive "only" Va(t) signal, and no load R and an initial Vcap=0 the output always equals the input.

Once a load R of any value is applied, the negative swing decays below 0V to conduct the diode which gradually charges up the Cap to Vcap=Va and the Vout goes from -Vf (diode) to Va-Vf, with a full swing of Va.

Then the load R could be removed, and the output should then not change.  (in theory)

The R load value thus controls the time it takes for a positive only signal to be negative clamped as well as the decay time for the droop.

Normally this is acceptable such that the droop is << 1% of the peak swing.

This is the common method for TV negative sync video clamp.

- The faster method preferred is an "active ground clamp" using a one shot created from detecting the negative edge to short circuit the signal to ground with a switch then open for a short as possible time determined by Rce or RdsOn*C.

  - If the signal started as a negative only biased signal, it would have clamped on the 1st -ve edge with diode Rs*C fast time then decay slow with load R*C time constant.

Still unsure?

[Try this bipolar input](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%2012%205e-9%202.008553692318767%2049%201%2050%0Ac%20256%20144%20208%20144%202%200.0000010000000000000002%204.359521112572347%0Ad%20256%20192%20256%20144%201%200.805904783%0Ag%20256%20192%20256%20208%200%0Ar%20288%20144%20288%20192%200%2010000%0Aw%20288%20192%20256%20192%200%0AR%20160%20144%20128%20144%200%202%20100000%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20256%20144%20256%20128%200%0Aw%20208%20144%20192%20144%200%0Ax%20257%20115%20280%20118%200%2014%20TP1%0Aw%20288%20144%20256%20144%200%0Ax%20110%20179%20143%20182%200%2012%2010Vpp%0Ar%20160%20144%20192%20144%200%201%0Ao%205%2064%200%202338%209.353610478917778%200.001461501637330903%200%20-1%200%0Ao%205%2064%200%202337%204.676805239458889%200.023384026197294447%200%20-1%200%0Ao%200%2064%200%202338%204.676805239458889%200.001461501637330903%201%20-1%200%0Ao%200%2064%200%202337%202.3384026197294445%200.023384026197294447%201%20-1%200%0Ao%203%2064%200%202338%2018.707220957835556%200.0007307508186654515%202%20-1%200%0Ao%203%2064%200%202337%209.353610478917778%200.001461501637330903%202%20-1%200%0A) (Falstad Sim) that monitors Vin, Vcap and Vout with currents below.
Note the initial clamp current.

[image]

Comment: Stewart i didnt understand what you meant by negative swing , Vi the input voltage waveform doesnt go below 0.

Comment: "Once a load R of any value is applied, the negative swing decays below 0V " ( to remove the DC offset)